# How to embed other application during deployment my application?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make the setup file of my appllication. i already made the deployment process and also been success to build the setup file as .msi file. but to run my application on other computer there need othe software to install like SQL server 2005 so that my database file can support on that system. also it need some other software to install. so i want to embed on my software the all necessary s/w and suppossed to install during installing my application. so i need to know what to do during deployment to attach these software.
what the solution for it in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you'll do this through your application's installer (ie, InstallShield, Inno-Setup, etc). Installers generally have the capability to launch other programs and/or incorporate other install scripts. Also, some installers will allow for hands-off installations (usually done with command-line switches), so that the install of the dependent program is seamless.

Comment: okey i have done these also sql server is also been downloaded but the path of the database backup file is not automatically been done. although i added the back up file into the installation process.

Comment: In that situation, I'd probably code a little C# program that determined the path of that backup file and created whatever database and tables need to be created at install. Then I'd have the installer call the program. I'm not sure how or if you can programatically determine the name of the database backup file.